# ASP.NET Forms Authentication - Too many redirects

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms-authentication

I have an ASP.NET 4.5 webforms site and trying to setup forms authentication.  I have an Account folder with a Login.aspx page within.  The main web.config contains the following:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880"/>
</authentication>
<authorization>
  <deny users ="?" />
  <allow users = "*" />
</authorization>
```

When I browse to the site, it appropriate redirects to `Account/Login.aspx` and then throws a browser error indicating

> Too Many Redirects

.  I am at a loss as to what could be wrong or where to go to troubleshoot next.  Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check if you have somewhere on your page that you have redirected to same page that you are in, or somewhere global, this endless loop.
eg `Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");`

Comment: I did in fact find the root cause.  Because I started with the WebForms template, VStudio setup an Account folder with a bunch of files to manage authentication, etc.  There was code in the StartupAuth that was causing the issue.  I ripped all of this out and was able to get the redirect working...sort of.  When I configure the web.config to point the loginUrl to an html page in the root of the web app, it redirects. When pointing to an ASPX, it indicates "access is denied".  If this should be a new thread, I will do so.

Comment: Just to close this out, I found my issue with the access denied.  I had the loginUrl in my web.config set to Login.aspx and denying anonymous access to everything.  I also have friendly URLs on.  By changing my loginUrl to Login (eliminating the extention), it fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this before and the issue was resolved by clearing cookies and browser history.

Comment: I appreciate your response.  Unfortunately, that did not resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check that your ASP .net State Service is running.  Starting this service resolved this problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Having an older version of the .Net Framework Runtime than is used by the application would also be the cause of this type of error.