# Browserstack not works(VS)

Tags: asp.net, browserstack

I try  to run my asp.net website too see how it will looks on mobile

So I try to use Browserstack

When I run website I have this Error

> http://localhost:63168/Mobile/Account/Login
>   net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS Login:1 GET
>   http://localhost:63168/Mobile/Account/Login
>   net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

[image]

Maybe anyone face this issue.

How I can solve it?

Comment: Have you checked if this works locally? Seems like an issue with your page. Similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21272485/asp-net-forms-authentication-too-many-redirects

Comment: Yes. Firstly I using mvc, not forms. Second yes. I run project locally and all okay @BountyHunter

Comment: In that case, I would recommend you connect with someone  at BrowserStack support. If the issue is at their end and you are able to resolve it, please post the answer here.