# iis rewrite redirect all pages to homepage

Tags: regex, redirect, iis, url-rewriting

I'm attempting to redirect all pages on a IIS site to the homepage/root. My rule below seems to work however I get a "localhost redirected you too many times" error.

The rule needs to exclude anything before the slash e.g mysite.com/mypage/

```
<rule name="redirect_all_bar_home_root" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^(.*)$" />
            <conditions>
              <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^$" negate="true"/>
            </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="http://localhost" />
        </rule>
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/21273935/3832970

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This rule will do that:

```
<rule name="redirect_all_bar_home_root" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^$" negate="true"/>
     <action type="Redirect" url="/" />
</rule>
```

Regex: `^$` is matching when string is empty (it is homepage)

`negate="true"` is negating regexp. `All URLs which are not homepage`

Comment: How can this work - as soon as you click to another page, doesn't it put you back on the first page again? How can you navigate around your website?

Answer (score 2):

I've just had a requirement to do this. The following rule will do what you need but with the exception that it will not attempt to redirect file urls so images still work on your homepage:

```
<rule name="RedirectAllToRoot" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^$" negate="true" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="/" redirectType="Temporary" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
</rule>
```

`redirectType="Temporary"` gives a 307 redirect status code